# Cannot run executable in Linux using Python

Tags: python, linux

I'm trying to launch Zoom using Python in Ubuntu. Here's my code:

```
import subprocess, sys

opener ="open" if sys.platform == "darwin" else "xdg-open"
subprocess.call([opener, '/opt/zoom/ZoomLauncher'])
```

When I run it, [this](https://i.redd.it/h6m18aam25j41.png) window pops up.
Even when I tried to run the Zoom.desktop file (which is allowed as executable in Dolphin), it opens in a text editor and doesn't execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the binary directly instead of using xdg-open:

```
subprocess.call(['/opt/zoom/ZoomLauncher'])
```

xdg-open is used to open files in the application configured for it in the desktop environment